How to specify function for given column in SQLite index?
DBContext.OnModelCreating
I use fluent API approach (not attributes) and I have index on some fields. Now I would like to apply a function on the column when creating index (to make NULLs indistinctive: Sqlite NULL and unique?).
I would prefer to avoid using raw SQL to achieve this, so there is a way to express this (i.e. apply function on column name) in EF Core when defining index?
        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryDb>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => new {e.Name, e.LanguageId}, "name_idx")
              .IsUnique();


How to express the notion of:
        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryDb>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => new {e.Name, IFNULL(e.LanguageId,0)},
              "name_idx").IsUnique();



i doubt that this will work,  you could use a generated column for the index

@nbk Well, it does not work, this is why I am asking :-) For generated column I have primary key, but I don't see a connection -- how one thing relates to the other?

generated columns are automatcally update when updating and inserting  a new row, so the generated columns has all the values with replacement if the null, so it has the correct values

@nbk, I am sorry but I still don't see how this relates to my question. Let's say I have such rows ("cat",1), ("dog",2),("cat",null),("cat",null). I would like such data would cause error (not unique with indistinctive NULL approach). If I add generated column to this mix this will always be unique, no matter what other data are.

Apparently it is not doable currently: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28360
